# How to put new css style to my button without removing old style?

Tags: css

I have a button with a style, and I want to change it to a new style without removing the existing style. So this is my currently button I have: http://jsfiddle.net/XaXg2/1/

HTML: `<a id="login-button" class="s3d blue">Search</a>`

CSS: `#login-button { float: left; height: 28px; line-height: 28px; width: 100px; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; color: #FFF; border-radius: 4px; background: #AC3; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; }`

I want to apply this new style without removing "login-button" style.

HTML: `<a href="#" class="s3d blue">New Search</a>`

CSS:

```
a.s3d  {
    clear: both;

    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
       -moz-border-radius:3px;
            border-radius:3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
       -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            box-shadow:0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    display: inline-block !important;
    font: 700 13px/36px 'Arial', Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 10px 11px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.35);
    width: 125px; }

a.blue {
    background: #65acc8;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 0, from(#65acc8), to(#4586ae));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#65acc8, #4586ae);
    background: linear-gradient(#65acc8, #4586ae);
    border-top: 1px solid #a1cdde;
    color: rgba(25,45,55,.9); }

a.blue:active {
    background: #4586ae;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 0, from(#4586ae), to(#65acc8));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4586ae, #65acc8);
    background: linear-gradient(#4586ae, #65acc8); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override your original CSS. Add `#login-button` to your selectors:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XaXg2/2/)**

```
#login-button {
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #AC3;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a#login-button.s3d {
    clear: both;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow:0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: inline-block !important;
    font: 700 13px/36px'Arial', Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 10px 11px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
    width: 125px;
}
a#login-button.blue {
    background: #65acc8;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 0, from(#65acc8), to(#4586ae));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#65acc8, #4586ae);
    background: linear-gradient(#65acc8, #4586ae);
    border-top: 1px solid #a1cdde;
    color: rgba(25, 45, 55, .9);
}
a#login-button.blue:active {
    background: #4586ae;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 0, from(#4586ae), to(#65acc8));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4586ae, #65acc8);
    background: linear-gradient(#4586ae, #65acc8);
}
```